# birt reports resources

Tags: eclipse, birt

I have a folder containing lots of birt reports. 
I have to open one report, modify it in an rcp application. 
I want to copy from the original workspace all the resources related to the report i am working on. 
All the resources , for all the reports and in a big folder ..how can i find out witch ones my report depends on, so i can copy them.
After i make the changes, i will deploy on jboss, the modified report, so that is why i need all the  reports resources, so my reports show all in jboss.

Is it the way to do it ? Is there a simpler way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it the way to do it ?

Depending on what kind of relation is between report design and resources, you could try to find them in rptdesign xml source.

For example I have a report with some images - their locations are referenced by `<expression name="uri" type="constant">my_image.png</expression>` tags, so i probably will find them manually using expression like `<expression name="uri"`. I would try also simple `.png`, `.jpg` patterns to find them, if I knew what kind of files they are.

Next, libraries are listed in Outline view. They are also searchable in rptdesign xml.

Next, some resouces are defined as report properties: Property Editor -> Resources -> Properties files, Jar files, Javascript files. Also listed in rptdesign xml.

> Is there a simpler way ?

I'm afraid, it isn't. If it is repetitive work, some script or xsl transformation on xml would do the job.

And be carefull with libraries - they can have their own dependencies.